# why sax parser give me limited output of characters?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am using SAX for parsing an XML data. I want to extract contents of a specific tag. The included text, which I want to extract, is 7-9 paragraphs and contains of nearly 1500 words. The problem is that whenever I ran my code I just get two first line of this text not the whole!

Sample of my input is something like this;

```
<class>
      <page>
        <text xml:space="preserve" bytes="14540">
          this is page 1
          name        = NAME.
          tag         = TAG
          This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
          ==
          This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
          ==
          This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
        </text>
      </page>

      <page>
        <text xml:space="preserve" bytes="2498">
          this is page 2
          name        = NAME.
          tag         = TAG
          This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
          ==
          This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
          ==
          This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
        </text>
      </page>
    </class>
```

This is a part of my code that print the content of specified tag (text);

```
 public void characters(char ch[],int start, int length) throws SAXException {
      String content = new String(ch, start, length);
        if (btext) {
            System.out.println("Text: " + content);
            btext = false; 
        }
 }
```

my result is something like this;

```
Start page 1
Text: this is page 1
name        = NAME.
End page
Start page 2
Text: this is page 2
name        = NAME.
End page
```

I want a result which prints all text inside the `<text> </text>`, but as you see it is just the first 2 line of text.
Would you please help me to find a solution?

Comment: Can you try removing the ` xml:space="preserve" bytes="2498"` and see what happens?

Comment: I try it, but nothing changed...

Comment: This could be a problem: `if (btext) {`  Where does btext get reset?  And what happens if `characters()` is called more than once because the text didn't all fit in a single input buffer?